# How to delete Azure Application Insights Troubleshooting guides

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I'm using troubleshooting guides (same functionality as workbooks) in Azure Application Insights to visualize some data. However I now wish to delete a certain troubleshooting guide. I can't for the life of me figure out how to do this. There is no button to be found anywhere just as there is no documentation to be found on this issue.

Does anyone know how to delete a troubleshooting guide?

A screenshot of the screen I'm stuck on:

[image]

Comment: can you please add an screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your Troubleshooting Guids Gallery, click the **Open**, then it will show all your REPORTS. Then click the three dots symbol on the right of the specific REPORT you want to delete, it will show **Delete** option .

[image]

[image]